# Menu bar shows wrong project when I launch android Studio from command line ~$ ./studio.sh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, android-studio, terminal, menubar

I have ubuntu 15.10 and android studio 2.1. If open android studio thru

`usr/share/applications/Android Studio`

the menu bar says Android Studio 2, which is what I want. However, when I open up studio through the command line~ `./studio.sh` it opens up studio and the menu bar always shows an old project at the top, even when I have a different project opened up. Any help would be appreciated. I'm somewhat new to linux.

Here is a screen shot to help explain
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  There is a file in `.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop` and I just deleted it.  Once I restarted Android Studion in the terminal: `~$studio.sh` it works fine. Also something worth saying, the same thing happened with eclipse.